Are Gaussian states equivalently defined as "ground and thermal states of quadratic Hamiltonians?"
There are several definitions of a (bosonic) gaussian state (related question).
One of them is given in the paper "Gaussian quantum channels" by J. Eisert and M.M. Wolf on page 3, equation 4. Here it is:

Gaussian states are exactly those having a Gaussian characteristic function
$$\chi_\rho(\xi) = e^{-\xi^T\Gamma\xi/4 + D^T\xi}.$$
Here, the $2n \times 2n$-matrix $\Gamma$ and the vector $D \in \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ are essentially the first and second
moments

The definition of the characteristic function is given in the same paper - equation 3.
But I also found some slides of Dr. Alessio Serafini for ICPT Winter College on Optics. Here on page 4 is the following definition

Let us define the set of Gaussian states as all the ground and thermal states of quadratic Hamiltonians with positive definite Hamiltonian matrix $H > 0$.

Are they really equivalent? How to prove it?

on a cursory look: "ground or thermal state" of an Hamiltonian $H$ here means (the normalised version of) $\rho=e^{-\beta H}$ for some $\beta\ge0$. If $H\ge0$ is quadratic, then we are talking about density matrices that are exponentials of quadratic terms. You then just need to verify that the characteristic functions of such states have the form you mention, and viceversa. Eg you can check that $\chi(\alpha)=\operatorname{tr}(e^{-\beta a^\dagger a}D(\alpha))$ is Gaussian (wrt $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$)
